# Anchor tag Mailto: not working Php WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I was modifying woocommerce email-footer.php ( email template file ) to add some custom social media links list including email link using mailto. My issue is only the email link if I clicked the email link it will only redirect me to my domain URL (sample: test.com ) mailto:myemail@ is missing but when I inspect element the HTML I see this https://mailto:myemail@test.com. What could be the issue here?

Also, I tried this

```
<a href=\"mailto:myemail@test.com\">
```

or create a php variable then echo in anchor tag but no result.

Below is my code

```
<ul class="footer-email__social-media">
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/email_fb.png" target="_blank" alt="facebook" title="follow us"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/email_instagram.png" target="_blank" alt="instagram" title="follow us"></a></li>
    <li><a href="mailto:myemail@test.com"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/email_email.png" target="_blank" alt="email" title="Email us"></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Note: I'm using child theme

Comment: Try this and tell me what you get? `<li><a href="mailto:myemail@test.com">Test</a></li>` , I suspect something broken in the image `src`.

Comment: From a UX perspective, you should avoid using mailto anchor tags.  When a user is not web savvy and they have a default mail client execute that is not set up, it can be a very frustrating experience.  Instead you should always link to a contact form page.

Comment: @WPDev I tried <li><a href="mailto:myemail@test.com">Test</a></li>  but the same result. It directs me to domain URL.

Comment: @JustinR. Can you please expand your comment with example code?

Comment: Use `<a href="/yourcontactpage.html">myemail@test.com</a>` instead of `<a href="mailto:myemail@test.com">`

Comment: You can swap in PHP code to replace the myemail@test.com with your image/text